# Propagation of error using Euler's first order method

Tags: finite-difference, computational-physics

I was estimating a falling object's position versus time by using a simple first order step function, where

```
for i=2:length(t) % We're using Euler, so we need an initial previous point to start

    t = t(i);        
    V = V + dv;        
    rho_i =    % Calculate our height and then pull rho from data        
    K = m/(mg - 0.5*C_d*A*V^2*rho_i);        
    dv = dt/K;    
    pos = pos - (V - V_previous)/2*dt;        
    V_previous=V;
    velocity_Vector(i) = V;
    pos_Vector(i) = pos;
end
```

Now I'm wondering, how much will the error be after this thing falls, like many many kilometers?

I know that it's a first order approximation, so there's error. But say I needed to know the bounds on that error; what would I do to calculate that?

Comment: Can we migrate it?

Comment: Hi John. Click the *flag* link, select the option "in need of moderator intervention" then type in a message asking for the question to be migrated.

Comment: Can you add the right hand side for ``rho_i``?

Answer (score 1):

In Euler's method, per step, the error is proportional to $(\Delta t)^2$, and over the entire interval, the cumulative error is of the order $\Delta t$, since the number of steps is proportional to $\frac {1}{\Delta t}$ and the errors add up. So one can put in the error as $$\Delta E \propto \Delta t$$ $$\Rightarrow \Delta E = K \Delta t$$ where $K$ is some constant that is specific to the parameters of the problem, and should be possible to determine using a few different step sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You would repeat the computation with various different values of the time step $\Delta t$ and get a table of the form

- $\Delta t=0.1, x(T)=12.345$
- $\Delta t=0.01, x(T)=12.033$
- $\Delta t=0.001, x(T)=12.003$
- $\Delta t=0.0001, x(T)=12.0003$

With data such as this, you can extrapolate what the most likely *exact* value will be (here simply 12.0), and with this you can then evaluate the error you would have for any of the previous choices for $\Delta t$.